# Separate between two section in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

How to make a height between the sections in a UITableView ? not just between the footer and header

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think ur talking about cell height

Answer (score 2):

You can set a header and footer for each section and then set the height of those headers and footers between each section to manage the space between them.

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: yes i know but the pb is : i have two section and i want to have a space between the section0 data and the section1 title.

nothing with the footer and header

Comment: markflowers gave you correct answer... Simply make the footer of section 0 higher (with it's bottom in color of tableview - or transparent) or header of section 1 higher (with is's top in color of tableview - or transparent). Your question has everything to do with (section) headers & footers. Don't forget: there are two types of headers/footers: section headers/footers and table header/footers. You can modify each and every one...